# How to prevent vue3 from regenerating elements in DOM when adding element to reactive array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In vue3, I have a array representing tabs and I push an object to it (when I click a button to open a new tab). My code is the below. But I notice an issue. Each time I push a new object to it, it re-generated all the `TabContent` objects executing all their `onMounted`. This is very inefficient. Is there a way that it only adds the new component to the DOM and ignore the rest?

```
        <template v-for="(tab, i) in tabs" :key="tab.id">
          <TabContent
            v-if="selected_request(tab.request.id)"
            v-show="tab.id === selected_tab?.id"
            v-model:tab="tabs[i]"
            v-model:api-call-loading="api_call_loading"
            v-model:specs-loading="specs_loading"
            :request="selected_request(tab.request.id)"
            :requests="requests"
            :accounts="accounts"
            :servers="servers"
            :result="result"
            :instance="null"
            :acquire-token="GetNewToken"
          />
        </template>
```

tabs is defined like this

```
// tabs
const tabs = ref([] as Tab[]);
```

Comment: The component would have to be completely unmounted before the `onMounted` hook could run again, otherwise Vue will always choose to reuse components. Even if the content of each tab changes, it shouldn't be remounting.  Is there a page refresh or any redirecting happening at the same time you push a new tab? There's not enough code provided to understand why your use case wouldn't be working normally.

Comment: I would also be wary of using v-if and v-show inside of a loop. Only pass the array of items you need to iterate over. You can pull them from a computed property that handles your if/show logic.